# idea/query for a package (unless it alread exists)

Tags: floats, labels

Imagine you're a silly person (like me), who has arm-twisted LaTeX into working as a DTP environment, for long (500-1200 page monstrographs) with *lots* of figures (which can't break across pages, obviously).

In the text in a fair number of places, I use simple language like 'as shown in the figure at the top of the next page'. Problem is, whenever I add/remove blocks of text, said reference to 'top of the next page' may no longer apply (since said figure might now be on the same page).

So, obvious solution is, refer to the figure by figure number, and let the reader 'find it'. Except that have figures with numbers and captions takes upon a fair bit of room, and I'm not using them as a way to reduce page space used. While I can 'internally label' the figure, without having a number/caption, and refer to it by that name in some sense, what I'm imagining is a package that 'knows' if a figure being referred to is on the same page, or not. In a perfect world, it would be a code snip that inserted the appropriate language: 'as shown below' is figure below reference to same (*on the same page*), 'as shown above' (same), or 'as shown on the next page' (if the figure in fact follows after a page break).

I've tried a variety of different things, and I know there are likely many bits of cleverness that I could employ, but I thought I'd start by describing the problem. I already have code that handles things like, 'insert blank page at the end if chapter ends on odd page', and so forth, but dealing with figures 'moving to another page' has me stumped. Again, trying to avoid the obvious and simple solution of referring to figures by figure number.

If what I'm describing isn't clear, we'll blame the cold meds, and I'll try again.

Comment: See eg the varioref package

Comment: So can one assume you don't use the `figure` environment and/or don't use `\caption`?

Comment: varioref is part of the core latex release so if you have latex at all you have this functionality.

Comment: Varioref! Thanks muchly -- seems like exactly what I was looking for.